# Where Do I Turn in Queen Endregas Quest?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've killed the cocoons and Queen Endregas but the quest doesn't have a check-box in my journal.  Does this quest turn in somewhere, if so where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can double-click on quests in your journal to switch them to the tracked quest. Sometimes (but not always) this will label your target objective on both the minimap, and the map page (default: m) itself.

The answer to your question, is Flotsam's Castellan (I think that's his title?) He's on the 2nd floor of the house directly to the left of the eastern Gate out of Flotsam (with Geralt facing towards Lobinden). He's also the one you talk to to complete the Nekker Contract, and he's involved with the first part of the Mystic River quest (finding a royal postbox) as well.

Comment: For some reason there is No 'flag' next to these monster quests in my log, thus I can't set them as the active quest. I'd tried that and should have mentioned that in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: @SMTF - Double-click the quest name. I had that issues getting the quests to switch at first as well. Trust me, and keep trying.